# Problem with Cleverref

Tags: cross-referencing, mdframed, cleveref

I have a problem with `cleveref`. Apparently, it does not work with `mdframed`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[left=2.50cm, right=2.00cm, top=2.00cm, bottom=2.00cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
% Definition of colors
\definecolor{toc_heading}{RGB}{0 51 89}
\definecolor{toc}{RGB}{0 119 138}
\definecolor{section}{RGB}{0 113 187}
\definecolor{subsection}{RGB}{0 115 207}
\definecolor{headline}{RGB}{77 112 139}
\definecolor{citecolor}{RGB}{0 124 48}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\mdfsetup{skipbelow=3ex}
\newtheorem{dummy}{dummy}[chapter]


\newmdtheoremenv [%
 hidealllines=true, leftline=true,
 linewidth = 2pt,  linecolor=section,
 leftmargin = 0,rightmargin = 0,%
 skipabove=\dimexpr\parskip+10pt\relax,
 innertopmargin = 0,splittopskip =3ex,
 innerrightmargin=2ex,splitbottomskip=3ex,innerbottommargin=2ex,
 ntheorem = false ,backgroundcolor=section!20%
]{theorem}[dummy]{Theorem}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\crefname{theorem}{theorem}{theorems}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter 1}
\begin{theorem}\label{thm:1}    bla
\end{theorem}
 This is \cref{thm:1}.

\end{document}
```

This code produces: This is ?? 1.1.

Has anyone encountered a similar problem?

Comment: I suggest to use the more versatile `tcolorbox` package which has built-in support for `cleveref`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The usage of `\newmdtheoremenv` is too early, 'fixing' the cross-reference format already before `cleveref` can apply with its own version of `\label` etc.

The definition of `theorem` must be shifted after loading of `cleveref`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[left=2.50cm, right=2.00cm, top=2.00cm, bottom=2.00cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
% Definition of colors
\definecolor{toc_heading}{RGB}{0 51 89}
\definecolor{toc}{RGB}{0 119 138}
\definecolor{section}{RGB}{0 113 187}
\definecolor{subsection}{RGB}{0 115 207}
\definecolor{headline}{RGB}{77 112 139}
\definecolor{citecolor}{RGB}{0 124 48}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\mdfsetup{skipbelow=3ex}
\newtheorem{dummy}{dummy}[chapter]


\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}


\newmdtheoremenv [%
 hidealllines=true, leftline=true,
 linewidth = 2pt,  linecolor=section,
 leftmargin = 0,rightmargin = 0,%
 skipabove=\dimexpr\parskip+10pt\relax,
 innertopmargin = 0,splittopskip =3ex,
 innerrightmargin=2ex,splitbottomskip=3ex,innerbottommargin=2ex,
 ntheorem = false ,backgroundcolor=section!20%
]{theorem}[dummy]{Theorem}

\crefname{theorem}{theorem}{theorems}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter 1}
\begin{theorem}\label{thm:1}    bla
\end{theorem}
 This is \cref{thm:1}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That was easy. As you may have noticed, I am simply a mathematician without any deeper understanding of the tex compiling process. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @julian: You're welcome. Happy TeXing!