# Cleveref referencing lemma with wrong name

Tags: cleveref

The problem is that when i write this

```
\begin{lemma} \label{lemma}
    Something
\end{lemma}

\cref{lemma}
```

It comes out like this:

[image]
My preamble looks like this

```
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\usepackage{cleveref}
```

What i want is for the reference to be named "lemma 0.1" not "theorem 0.1"

Comment: `\usepackage{cleveref}` **before** `\newtheorem` etc....

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/405873/problem-with-cleverref

Comment: Please tell us whether you use the `amsthm` or the `ntheorem` package.

Comment: Christians comment was the answer. I use the asthma package